# Keeping function call signatures consistent for a function that accepts a superset of another function's arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function (`foo`) that is a <s>convenience function</s> wrapper for another function (`bar`).  `foo` calls `bar`, then performs another couple of tasks on the output.  For example:

```
def bar(bar_arg, bar_kw=None):
    #do some stuff
    return ret

def foo(bar_arg, foo_arg, bar_kw=None, foo_kw=None):
    ret = bar(bar_arg, bar_kw)
    ret.some_method(foo_arg, foo_kw=foo_kw)
```

I would like the call signature for `foo` to contain the keywords and arguments from `bar` so that a user inspecting `foo` knows what they can pass, however, I would like to avoid maintaining the full list of arguments myself since `bar` tends to change as the package it comes from is updated and its argument list is long.  Since `foo` always calls `bar` with the full list of arguments and keywords that `bar` accepts, I don't see that I should need to maintain the list myself.

Is there a way to build the call signature for `foo` based on the call signature for `bar`?  Additionally, is there a way to capture the inputs to `foo` in a dictionary or namespace so that I can easily separate the arguments and keywords used by `foo` from those used by `bar`?

Note, I know about *args and **kwargs.  They leave the function signature ambiguous, though, and don't inform the user of what arguments and keyword arguments are allowed.

Edit: I should note that my use case is significantly more complex than this example.  The external function being called (`bar`) is `matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase`.  The calling function (`foo`) is a class method for a plotting class that is used in numerous applications of my own that others are likely to use in the future.  `foo` creates a colorbar, then performs additional work on the colorbar based on additional arguments and keywords that are not accepted by `ColorbarBase`.

Comment: You can *probably* have a decorator (that gets the `bar` reference as argument) do that for you.

Comment: I think you mean `ret.some_method`, and also `return ret`.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, edited.

Comment: @Thrustmaster I'm sure you're right, I just can't seem to formulate the right decorator in my head...

Comment: @Vorticity check my decorator answer below and mark correct if its what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Since `bar()` wraps `foo()` which calls the `ColorbarBase` constructor, write a decorator around the `foo()` call. The decorator makes modifications to the arguments passed into bar before calling `foo()`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib as mpl


def bar(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Change args, kwargs for calling foo()
        f(*new_args,**new_kwargs)
        return
return wrapper


@bar
def foo(*new_args, **new_kwargs):
    return mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
```

For example, the following returns a `ColorbarBase` object to the caller give an initial set of parameters which are then modified by `bar()`. In this way the call signature for `foo()` is based on the call signature for `bar()`.

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
cmap = mpl.cm.cool
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=5, vmax=10)

ret = foo(ax1, 
          cmap=cmap,
          norm=norm,
          orientation='horizontal')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to leave out `foo`. Keep the API short and sweet with just the simple building blocks that users need so that they can quickly learn how to use your library. Programmers can very easily then create the convenience functions that they actually want and not be distracted by the ones you think they want.

If your actual functions are more complicated than they look in the question then update the question to show that. Right now it's clear and explicit for a programmer to simply write

```
my_bar = bar(bar_arg, bar_kw)
my_bar.some_method(foo_arg, foo_kw=foo_kw)
```

for themselves. Any reader knows exactly what's going on and doesn't have to parse a long argument list, and the extra line of code is fine.

Comment: I generally agree with you, but, like you assume, my use case is more complex than this.  The function being called is matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.  It is being called inside a class method that does additional work on the resulting colorbar and which accepts additional arguments and keywords.  I figured that it would be obvious that my use case was more complex than the pseudocode I posted.

Comment: I just edited my answer to partially explain how my case is more complex than the pseudocode example.

Comment: @Vorticity if, say, there's no such thing as `bar.some_method` but rather it's several complicated lines, then consider *creating* a `bar.some_method` or `some_function(bar)` so that you can get back to simple building blocks with cleanly separated arguments. If that's no good, show the actual code or some more realistic pseudocode because your description isn't very informative.